# Using Extern variables from C header files with C++

Tags: c++, c, extern

I have a library that is written for me in C. In the library there is a variable that I need to use 
In foo.h (which is in C)

```
extern mystruct foobar;
```

In bar.h (which is in C++)
I have the following class.

```
#include foo.h

class myfoo { 

private:
   mystruct foobar;
}
```

What I would like to know is if I create an array of myfoo, will each instance of foobar be referencing the same variable, or will each instance be its own unique instantiation of the myfoo that independent from the other myfoo foobars?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here’s the deal: you are **not** using `foo.h`’s `foobar` variable in `bar.h` (this is particularly true because `foo.h` only *declares* `foobar`, a definition would have to be in an implementation file). Rather, you are redeclaring a variable with the same name and type in the scope of the class.

With that, all the normal rules for an instance member variable apply. In particular, every instance of `myfoo` will have its own instance of `foobar`.

If you removed the declaration from `foo.h` nothing would change: the declaration is completely irrelevant for your `bar.h` file.

Answer (score 3):

The `foobar` member inside the class definition of `myfoo` is defined at a different scope from the `foobar` at global scope. The are different variables, unrelated to each other, except that they are of the same type, and happen to have the same name (although at different scopes).

If you create an array of `myfoo` objects, each one will have an instance of `mystruct`. All of those instances will be separate from the one declared in the global scope.

Comment: They only have the same *unqualified* name.

Comment: Ben - agreed. I was trying not to introduce too much additional vocabulary, and was sacrificing a bit of specificity and precision to keep the description simpler. I could go back and edit if folks find that imprecision distracting.

Comment: @jwismar Right level of detail.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to know is if I create an array of myfoo, will each
>   instance of foobar be referencing the same variable, or will each
>   instance be its own unique instantiation of the myfoo that independent
>   from the other myfoo foobars?

if you do this:

```
#include foo.h

class myfoo 
{ 
private:
    mystruct foobar;
};

void func()
{
    myfoo f[3];
    // ...
}
```

you create 3 different *myfoo* objects, each with its own *foobar* instance.

if you change the myfoo declaration as follows:

```
#include foo.h

class myfoo 
{
private:
   static mystruct foobar;
};

// this extra declaration is required for 
// static member variables
mystruct myfoo::foobar;

void func()
{
    myfoo f[3];
    // ...
}
```

*then* the three instances of myfoo will share their single instance of foobar.

**NOTE**:

The `class myfoo` declaration may be in either a '.h' or a '.cpp' file.

The `mystruct myfoo::foobar;` declaration may only appear once, so it normally has to be in a '.cpp' file (or '.cc' or whatever you use).